# Why do we have so many usb tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are four tags which I would like to focus upon:

1. [usb-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive)
2. [usb-storage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-storage)
3. [usb-c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-c)
4. [usb-device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-device)

Do we really require these many tags?

I feel [usb-c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-c) tag is not good one. It sets a precedent that we can have tags like micro-usb, usb-a, etc.

Please decide what should be done to all these tags.

Comment: USB C should be split into two tags: \[usb-3.x\] and \[usb-4.x\], would you agree? when someone mentions usb-c in a question, that is usually what they are talking about anyway? I could see the standards having a place on the site, just not an external hardware spec., maybe link them? so USBC is there, but in name only.

Comment: Nobody even cares about [tag:usb-c] and [tag:usb-device]. 0 watchers on both.

Comment: @Muru From what I been hearing, both vga and HDMI technologies are supposed to be replaced by usb-c soon; its mainstream application is still fairly new and growing. That said, you're right as this probably just encourages questions that are better suited on other platforms. +1

Answer (score 10):

I'll add my opinion on each tag. But in summary, I say we should get rid of all of them except [usb-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive).

1. [usb-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive)

   Excerpt:

   > For questions regarding storage drives that connect using a USB port.

   This tag is used a lot, especially since it has [2 synonyms](https://askubuntu.com/tags/usb-drive/synonyms), [flash-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/flash-drive) and [pendrive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/pendrive). Currently, it has 1315 questions tagged with it.
   **This one we should keep**.
2. [usb-storage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-storage)

   This tag has no excerpt with 187 questions tagged with it.
   I would recommend making it a **synonym of the [usb-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive) tag** above. *The excerpt of that tag even mentions storage drives explicitly.*
3. [usb-c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-c)

   I'm not sure if this tag has any use at all with 101 questions and 0 watchers.
   I would **recommend deleting it** and retagging with [usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb).
4. [usb-device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-device)

   This tag isn't being used much with a mere 34 questions and 0 watchers. It's mostly used for external devices plugged in through a USB interface. Nowadays, almost all external devices use a USB interface for connection as long as it's not a very old machine or Apple product (which recently is also shifting to USB).
   I would **recommend deleting it** and retagging with [usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb).

Comment: You're recommending that we should remove all of them except `usb-drive` (agreed) but then saying we should retag the last two as `usb`. Did you mean retag as `usb-drive`?

Comment: @terdon I meant `usb` because those questions aren't necessarily related to USB drives.